# Executing MapReduce job using oozie workflow in hue giving wrong output

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm trying to execute MapReduce job using oozie workflow in hue. When I submit the job, oozie successfully executes but I don't get the expected output. It seems that either mapper or reducer never invoked.here is my workflow.xml:

```
<workflow-app name="wordCount" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4">
    <start to="wordcount"/>
    <action name="wordcount">
        <map-reduce>
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.input.dir</name>
                    <value>/user/root/jane/inputPath</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.output.dir</name>
                    <value>/user/root/jane/outputPath17</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.mapper.class</name>
                    <value>MapReduceGenerateReports.Map</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.reducer.class</name>
                    <value>MapReduceGenerateReports.Reduce</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.mapper.new-api</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.reducer.new-api</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
        </map-reduce>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="kill"/>
    </action>
    <kill name="kill">
        <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

Can anyone please tell what is the problem?

my new workflow.xml :

```
<workflow-app name="wordCount" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4">
    <start to="wordcount"/>
    <action name="wordcount">
        <map-reduce>
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.input.dir</name>
                    <value>/user/root/jane/inputPath</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.output.dir</name>
                    <value>/user/root/jane/outputPath3</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.mapper.new-api</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.reducer.new-api</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapreduce.map.class</name>
                    <value>MapReduceGenerateReports$Map</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapreduce.reduce.class</name>
                    <value>MapReduceGenerateReports$Reduce</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name> mapred.output.key.class</name>
                    <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.output.value.class</name>
                    <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.Text</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
        </map-reduce>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="kill"/>
    </action>
    <kill name="kill">
        <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

jobtracker log:

1)

```
Kind    % Complete  Num Tasks   Pending Running Complete    Killed  Failed/Killed
Task Attempts
map 100.00%
1   0   0   1   0   0 / 0
reduce  100.00%
0   0   0   0   0   0 / 0
```

2)

```
   Kind Total Tasks(successful+failed+killed)   Successful tasks    Failed tasks    Killed tasks    Start Time  Finish Time
    Setup    1   1   0   0  5-Apr-2014 18:36:22 5-Apr-2014 18:36:23 (1sec)
    Map  1   1   0   0  5-Apr-2014 18:33:27 5-Apr-2014 18:33:33 (5sec)
    Reduce   0   0   0   0      
    Cleanup  1   1   0   0  5-Apr-2014 18:33:33 5-Apr-2014 18:33:37 (4sec)
```

Comment: can you share the logs both oozie log as well as the job tracker logs. Oozie will be running a invoker job first and then the actual map reduce, you can differentiate it in the job tracker ui.

Comment: I have added the jobtracker logs. Kindly check.Map is showing complete status as 1 and reduce is 0. I feel reducer is not invoking. If u have  any solution for this please let me know.

Comment: Check for the following . 1. mapreduce instead of mapred or vice versa 2. Does your namenode have hdfs://<ip-or dns-name> ?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the instructions for using the new API [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OOZIE/Map+Reduce+Cookbook)

> However, if you really need to run MapReduce jobs written using the 20 API in Oozie, below are the changes you need to make in workflow.xml.
>
> 1. change mapred.mapper.class to **mapreduce.map.class**
> 2. change mapred.reducer.class to **mapreduce.reduce.class**
> 3. add mapred.output.key.class
> 4. add mapred.output.value.class
> 5. and, include the following property into MR action configuration

Comment: I tried as you said. but after that I'm geeting the following error:

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: MapReduceGenerateReports$Map cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:631)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:330)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1438)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)

Comment: I have updated the new workflow.xml above. how can i solve this ? Solution to this issue is greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Can you post the code for your mapper?  The error tells me that its not implementing the new API.

Comment: it's written using old API.

Comment: You should be able to to just remove the properties that tell oozie to use the new API.  Default is old

Comment: Thank you. I removed and tried. Oozie executes successfully but output is reading the same input file. Is it not invoking properly? any idea?

Comment: Can you look at the job tracker logs and see if they show anything?  Its always a pain to debug oozie issues

Comment: I checked the jobtracker it's not clear.what i understood is the reducer is not invoked and because of that the same inputfile records are copied to output.I have added the piece of log above. kindly check and please let me know if you have any better solution.:)

Comment: Well... It doesnt say anything about failed maps/reduces.  Whats wrong with the output and does it work from the command line?

Comment: No I'm not using command line. I'm just uploading the jar and then settings the properties for it. basically I'm following this link: http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/Working+with+Hue

Comment: Problem with output is instead of giving count of words, it's just reading same input records and displaying.(I'm trying to execute wordcount mapreduce job).