# Oozie job failed due to "not org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper" while running through hue

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, oozie, hue, oozie-coordinator

I am trying to run wordcount program through oozie job.
When I run the wordcout jar manually like `hadoop jar wordcoutjar /data.txt /out`  .It runs fine and give me output.
Here is the details of mapper code of my wordcount program.

```
    public class MapperWordcount extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>{
        private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
        private Text word = new Text();

        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String line = value.toString();
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
            while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
                context.write(word, one);
            }
        }

    }
```

When I execute it through oozie job ,the error is like below:

```
 2015-07-31 00:39:23,357 FATAL [IPC Server handler 29 on 40854] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Task: attempt_1438294006985_0011_m_000000_3 - exited : java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:446)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
            at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
            ... 9 more
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: class com.mr.wc.MapperWordcount not org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper
            at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2108)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.getMapperClass(JobConf.java:1109)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:38)
            ... 14 more
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: **class com.mr.wc.MapperWordcount not org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper**
            at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2102)
            ... 16 more
```

My pom.xml is like this .

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
```

Comment: Probably similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22863419/executing-mapreduce-job-using-oozie-workflow-in-hue-giving-wrong-output

Answer (score 0):

I got a same problem here the actual problem was code is referring to old map reduce libraries while at runtime it is trying to find new map reduce librarires.

In Gradle

```
compile("org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:2.4.0")
```

and in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

and change all the references in Mapper and reducer from org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper to org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper